# How to change image axis labels

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to change the image axis labels with some latitude/longitude but I can't find how to do it. I tried some basic commands like:

```
imagesc(data)
axis(meshgrid([-180:20:180],[-90:20:90]))
colorbar
```

but these expression appeared:

> imagesc(data),axis(meshgrid([-180:20:180],[-90:20:90])), colorbar
>   Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar
>   values.
>
> ```
> Error in axis>allAxes (line 448)
> result = all(ishghandle(h)) && ...
>
> Error in axis (line 57)
> if ~isempty(varargin) && allAxes(varargin{1}).
> ```

Can anybody help me? FYI, my image axis labels are the data order (from 0 to N).

My desired results is an image looks like a world map, with graticule/grid lines as the axes. It should be looked like [this](http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/wgs84/gravitymod/egm2008/egm08_gis.html):

[image]

Comment: Hi. You'll have to be a little more informative than _"... But it didn't work"_. Can you provide an example of the desired result?

Comment: M_Map is useful for this sort of thing: http://www.eos.ubc.ca/~rich/map.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From your question I infer that you want to set the x-axis labels from -180 to 180, and the y-axis labels from -90 to 90. To do this, you should change the `XTickLabel` and `YTickLabel` properties of the axis object (note that you'll also need to adjust the number of ticks in each axis by modifying the `XTick` and `YTick` properties accordingly).

So, assuming that your image is stored in the matrix `data` and you display it with `imagesc(data)`, here's how to change the tick labels in the x-axis to be from -180 to 180:

```
xticklabels = -180:20:180;
xticks = linspace(1, size(data, 2), numel(xticklabels));
set(gca, 'XTick', xticks, 'XTickLabel', xticklabels)
```

Similarly, here's how to change the tick labels in the y-axis to be from -90 to 90:

```
yticklabels = -90:20:90;
yticks = linspace(1, size(data, 1), numel(yticklabels));
set(gca, 'YTick', yticks, 'YTickLabel', flipud(yticklabels(:)))
```

This is what it should look like:

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce your proposal for all flips vertical and/or horizontal here http://stackoverflow.com/q/39923300/54964

Answer (score 3):

Can't say I fully understand what you mean, so here goes. To add a `label` to an axis use `xlabel` and `ylabel`, for example:

```
xlabel('time [sec]'); ylabel('Amplitude');
```

To change the labels of the axis **ticks**, use something like:

```
plot(1:4)
set(gca,'Xtick',1:4,'XTickLabel',{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'})
```

Working with `imagesc` you may want to add this line:

```
set(gca, 'YDir', 'reverse');
```

this will set the numbers on the Ticks growing for the bottom left corner...

Comment: I've tried your script, but the result's not look like my desired result (a worl map)

Comment: There's very little I can do to answer this comment.